# Squish Remote Control(UI of qt app) from py script

Tags: squish

Is there any way i can start Squish Remote Control(UI of qt app) from py script.Trying to avoid Squish IDE.
I searched in squish api but hasn't find solution.I guess Remote System should be used.
from remotesystem import RemoteSystem
def main():
try:
remotesys = RemoteSystem("localhost", 4322)
except Exception as e:
test.fail("Connect to squishserver", str(e))

Comment: What do you want to do? Execute a test suite on the local computer, but let the AUT be automated on a remote computer? And is the AUT (Application Under Test) already running, or is Squish supposed to start it for you?

Comment: I already bilt a script and i managed to run tests in robotframework. AUT is already running and i can attach to it,but to verify some changes i need Remote Control Viewer(image search,higlight and so on). Can i get that screen without using Squish IDE?

Answer (score 0):

You might follow this instruction to use squishtest as a module in your python script to interact with the Gui.

[Using Squish as a module in other Python scripts, applications](https://kb.froglogic.com/squish/howto/using-squish-module-python-scripts-applications/)

If you are using the Python Squish interpreter and the Squishserver you can use other IDEs to write your tests.