# Can you use Squish for Android with other IDEs?

Tags: python, qt, squish

I find Squish IDE extremely clunky and counter intuitive. I wanted to try Squish testing but I would like to use some other tools to write scripts, like VSCode or PyCharm. Is it possible? Could you point me to some resources that would introduce me to this set up?

Or maybe some other solutions than Squish to allow UI testing for Qt apps on Android?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found some answers after following [Squish Remote Control(UI of qt app) from py script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71206466/squish-remote-controlui-of-qt-app-from-py-script)

Additionally, froglogic support advises recording the tests with squishrunner utility and then editing the file with text editors.

```
squishrunner --testsuite suite_AddressBook_py --record tst_general --useWaitFor
```

I am not sure if it is possible to enable code completion in IDEs other than Squish IDE.

Comment: Code completion is tricky for the symbols in the AUT, because those depend on GUI toolkit, its version and the symbols the AUT brings to the table.

More easily to achieve is completion of the standard Squish functions, but even that requires the used IDE to inspect the symbols live, or that you set up "fake imports" ("if False: import squish_functions" - and you need to provide "squish_functions.py" and its content yourself) for the desired functions, which is never used when actually executing the script.

Comment: Thanks for your input, do you have any guides on standard Squish functions completion? @frog.ca

Comment: Sadly, no. But at the minimum all you need is a function defined as startApplication(aut_name) in a custom module and "import" it via "if False from squish_functions import *" to "trick" your Python IDE into offering the functions inside of squish_functions.py for completion, because it does not understand that "if False" means that this import statement will never be actually executed.

Comment: Thanks @frog.ca, I will see how far I can get with Appium then.